# How do I calculate the area of a rectangular diagonal

Tags: geometry

I need to find a way to calculate the Area of a rectangular diagonal, this is what I have so far:

- Opposite: 15.1 m
- Hypotenuse: 23.5 m
- Adjacent: x

EDIT: The picture was wrong.

Comment: What is a "rectangular diagonal"?

Comment: What you've given are what seems to be the dimensions of a right-triangle.

Comment: @nbubis  This is a rectangular diagonal, http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/cms_upload/Fig429079.jpg

Comment: I suspected as such, but then what do you mean by area? do you mean the length?

Comment: @amWhy can you explain, those are the bits I have, not sure if the "Adjecent" is equal, in fact, it is equal to the opposite "Adjecent" on the other side of the rectangular diagonal.

Comment: @nbubis A diagonal is a line joining two nonconsecutive vertices of a polygon or polyhedron. Thus a rectangular diagonal is...

Comment: Thus, OP, you can't calculate the area of a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your link to the picture of a "[rectangular diagonal](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/cms_upload/Fig429079.jpg)," it looks like you are given the dimensions of one of the right triangles formed by the diagonal of the rectangle. To solve for $x$, we use the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) which pertains to right-triangles: and note that $$\text{Hypotenuse Length}^2 = \underbrace{\text{Adjacent Length}^2}_{\large x^2} + \text{Opposite Length}^2$$

Then once you've found $x$, you can multiply $(x \times \;\text{Opposite Length})$ to determine the area of the rectangle.

Comment: Yes, almost, but, I have H & O, I do not know A and I have to calculate the area of the entire rectangular which is a rectangular diagonal.

Comment: after your last edit, things become more clear, do you have any link to a website which explains this with basic steps? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Solve for $$x = \sqrt{\text{hypotenuse}^2 - \text{ opposite}^2}$$

Comment: A quick search gave me this, "Pythagorean theorem" - not sure if I should use that?

Comment: BTW, that link to the picture is just a sample one, it's not the actual problem or rectangular which is found in a math book which I am using.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's exactly what I've used in my post: the Pythagorean theorem holds for any right-triangle: a triangle with a $90^\circ$ angle.

Comment: The two sides of which form the right angle (the angle that's 90 degrees) are called the legs of the triangle (here, that's what $x$ (adjacent) and "opposite" represent). The hypotenuse refers to the longest side of a right triangle (the side directly opposite the right angle). The hypotenuse is the diagonal of your rectangle, in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Pythagorean Theorem solved it, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome, John!